# How to merge two different rows based on one column value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a result set which returns results like this,

```
   ID     Q_Number      INC_Date1       INC_Date2             OUT_Date1        OUT_Date2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8322445  Q8322445  2014-03-06 00:00:00  2014-05-14 13:31:00    NULL          NULL
8322445  Q8322445         NULL            NULL           2014-05-16 09:22:00  2014-05-20 07:29:00
```

Actually I want to get the date difference between all the columns.

It works for difference between INC_Date 2 and INC_Date1, OUT_Date2 and OUT_Date1 but it does not work for OUT_Date1 - INC_Date2.

I'm not sure if taking max of the dates will work out for the entire table.

Here is a sample of output that I want,

```
ID     Q_Number      INC1INC2Diff       INC2OUT1Diff         OUT1OUT2Diff 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
8322445  Q8322445       69                 1                    3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it a query or you want a permanent change in your table?

Comment: It's not clear what the output should be. Could you add some sample input and desired output to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your query this is a guess, but to merge the rows in the example you can use aggregation like this:

```
select 
    ID, 
    Q_Number,       
    max(INC_Date1) as INC_Date1,
    max(INC_Date2) as INC_Date2,
    max(OUT_Date1) as OUT_Date1,
    max(OUT_Date2) as OUT_Date2
from 
    table -- or from your query used as a derived table
group by 
    id, Q_Number
```

Update for changes in the question:

```
select 
    ID, 
    Q_Number,       
    DATEDIFF(d,max(INC_Date1), max(INC_Date2) ) as INC1INC2Diff,
    DATEDIFF(d,max(INC_Date2), max(OUT_Date1) ) as INC2OUT1Diff,
    DATEDIFF(d,max(OUT_Date1), max(OUT_Date2) ) as OUT1OUT2Diff
from 
    t
group by 
    id, Q_Number
```

Comment: @g.pickardou I don't see anything in the question that asks for update/delete, only how to merge the two rows to one, which is what my query does.

Comment: You are right, your interpretation could be also right, now I've asked in the original question's comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you always know that

- Some rows will always have dates in INC date 1 and 2 and always have NULL in OUT date 1 and 2
- Some rows will always have dates in OUT date 1 and 2 and always have NULL in OUT date 1 and 2
- You will always have matching 'pairs' of these rows

you can do a simple SELECT with INNER JOIN on ID and/or Q_Number depending on what your key is SELECTing the NON NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

Without using SPs and cursors it seems to you should do it two steps (although it could be one atomic transaction if there is a need. Note: Do not do the two steps in one transaction if there is no problem if the second command does not succeed, instead try it again.)

1. UPDATE with a correlated subquery. The correlation goes to the subquery's WHERE and it is the equality of the inner and outer query's Q_Number
2. A DELETE where you are deleting the useless leftover (the rows that still contains NULL after the UPDATE)